# Automated Timing for Video Subtitles

Tags: subtitles

I have got a video clip and a 100% accurate text file (containing subtitles). Is there any way where I can convert the text file into a timed SRT subtitle file?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How is the txt-file structured? What do you mean by "100% accurate"?

Comment: Like a tapescript. Correct word by word. What lacks are just the timecodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no professional tool that does this, as far as I know. It is never done, presumably because it would not be good enough and would need to be corrected by a human anyway.

There are of course many subtitling applications into which you can import your transcript and then do the spotting by hand. And they have varying features to make it easier/faster/more precise.

However, Youtube does offer [automatic timing of transcripts](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2734799?hl=en). You may want to try it.

Using that, you could:

- upload your video to youtube
- upload your transcript
- wait for their software to do the automatic timing
- download the youtube captions
- ... then probably still do manual corrections.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as I have explored, I have tried Youtube, which does automatic captioning and automatic timing. However, can I upload my 100% script (without timing, just plain text) to increase the accuracy of the automatic captioning of Youtube? Second, I have also tried Adobe Premiere and Adobe After Effects, which does automatic captioning and automatic timing. If I have provided a transcript for reference, Adobe will improve the accuracy of its automatic captioning, which greatly saves the time of manual editing.